# How To Customize the Share Menu

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock

How do I customize the share menu in my app. What I want to do is change the share menu to only show a couple of options and then drop all other options in into an Other.. submenu.

I've found a lot of references to making an app available as a sharing option, but nothing about customizing the share menu from within an app.

Also, I need need a solution that if at all possible, works in 2.2 +. And if it's relevant, I'm using ActionBarSherlock in the app.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I customize the share menu in my app

Download the source for it, refactor it into a new package, modify it to suit, and use your modified version.

> And if it's relevant, I'm using ActionBarSherlock in the app.

Then [here is the ABS implementation of `ShareActionProvider`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/widget/ShareActionProvider.java), for you to download, refactor, modify, and use.

Comment: I've been working on this off and on. Can you give me some more details?

I'm beginning to think that I don't want the ActionBarSherlock in this case. I have a hybrid app and the actual share icon the user clicks is in the webapp.

So you said 
>Download the source for it, refactor it into a new package, modify it to suit, and use your modified version.

I'm not sure I know what you mean. I only want to override the share menu in my app and I want the change to be included in .apk for my app.

Comment: @BradRhoads: "I have a hybrid app and the actual share icon the user clicks is in the webapp" -- if your hybrid app container is supplying you with a native action bar, talk to them about your requirements. If by "the actual share icon the user clicks is in the webapp" you mean "the action share icon the user clicks is implemented in HTML/CSS/JS/PNG", then you do not have an action bar, nor a share menu to override. Unless somebody has created an HTML equivalent of `ShareActionProvider` for this purpose, you are on your own.